# OPCDA read time

Tags: c#, com, opc, response-time, opc-da

I am polling an OPCDA server for data every second. I use the standard .NET DLL's from OPC Foundation to achieve this.

My service is located on the same server as the OPCDA server. However, my read times are often around 900-1000ms. Is this normal or something wrong in my code or server setup? I poll around 20 OPCDA tags. What is a "standard" response time of such an operation or is it impossible to say?

Comment: For better performance you could maybe switch to an OPC UA Server which support HDA or use an OPC UA Gateway, that exposes your OPC DA tags as OPC UA Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound normal, but it's impossible to say for certain without knowing what the source of the data is.

Comment: What information would be needed to give a more specified answer of what could be wrong?

Comment: Something like... "oh yeah, on the other end is one or more horrible old Modbus devices talking on RS485... yeah that's probably why comms are slow".

Comment: Note that polling periodically is recommended against in OPC. You should be using subscriptions. Why? Because if the read from the device takes around 1 second, and you are polling at 1 second rate, your reading tread will have no time left to do its processing job, plus any fluctuation in the read time will immediately affect you. With subscriptions, you'd just wait for the incoming notifications and then process them, giving more stable timing, and allowing the server to make the best decisions about how to obtain the data periodically.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have two questions regarding your answer ZbynekZ. One, if I use subscriptions, is it guaranteed that the subscription notifications appear in correct time order? Two, are notifications supported by all OPC-DA servers?

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation of OPC DA interface you use to fetch data from the server and what parameters you pass to it.

If you use synchronous reads then problem definitely on server side or its backend (meaning that it takes too much time for server to read actual data).

If you use asynchronous reads (subscriptions) check parameter named like 'update rate'. It defines how often new data will be sent to client. E.g. if it is 1 second client will receive new data NOT faster than 1 second.

Subscriptions are supported by all OPC DA versions. If server doesn't implement this interface you will not be able to read asynchronously and will get error code like 'not implemented'.

Answer (score 0):

What OPC server are you using?  There may be a setting to keep the update rate fixed or respect the client update rate.